# Can these regex urls get indexed by google without internal links?

Tags: jquery, django, url, routes, google-search

My urls have the regex pattern `r'/index/(?P<movie_id>\d)'` i.e index/(any movie_id) and then I grab the movie info with an api by jQuery.

There are millions of webpages like these. One for each movie. And all the backend code works only with the specific movie_id parameter. Would such pages be indexed by google if they have no internal links connecting within the website?

The only links are from an ajax search bar which works only when someone types, which cannot be considered an internal link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your urls to be indexed by google, you need to submit your sitemap to google. i don't think google will index your dynamic links on its own without submitting the sitemap.

You can read more about django sitemap [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/sitemaps/)

Comment: Problem is, I have more than a million pages. One on every movie in the movie database. So is a sitemap feasible?

Comment: Yes, you will be hosting the sitemap on a single url and it can be created within ten lines of code.

Comment: Dunno why I never knew about django sitemaps. But u pretty much saved my life....Thanks!